# jqgrid select: having different option text in form than on table

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

If i have a these select options...

```
var OptionsOnTable = "1:OptionA extra text;2:OptionB extra text;3:OptionC extra text;"
var OptionsOnDialogForm = "1:OptionA;2:OptionB;3:OptionC;"
```

On this column...

```
{name:"col2",index:"col2",editable:true,formatter:"select",edittype:"select"},
editoptions:{value: OptionsOnTable}
```

What would be the best way to go about changing the option text on the dialog form but leaving the option text on the table as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `formatter: "select"` then the texts displayed in the grid based of `formatoptions.value` or `editoptions.value`. On the other side it will be used only `editoptions.value` during form editing. So you can specify both `formatoptions.value` *and* `editoptions.value` for one column. It will solve your problem.

For example I used the following definition of the `ship_via` column in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FormatterSelect.htm):

```
formatter: "select", formatoptions: { value: "FE:_FedEx_;TN:_TNT_;IN:_Intim_", defaultValue: "IN" },
edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "IN" },
stype: "select", searchoptions: { value: ":Any;FE:=FedEx=;TN:=TNT=;IN:=Intim=", sopt: ["eq", "ne"] } }
```

So one sees three *different* textes in selects: one in grid, another during editing and the third one in the searching dialog:

[image]

and

[image]